# Angular progress-bar delay / or value updater

Tags: jquery, angularjs, progress-bar, tablesorter

I'm using the angular progress-bar directive in a table created with ng-repeat, along with a jquery table sorter plugin.

Problem is that the initial animation will not be done/shown at all; when user refresh a page, he will get tables with progresses already set to it's correct level / value.

If I change values later, with a dummy button, animation will be shown correctly.

My question is:

How can I delay the starting animation, in order to show the progress from 0 (some initial value) to some specific value - 64, e.g.

If you have a suggestion to use some different approach, don't hesitate to tell me, I'm open minded.

Comment: can you provide code/fiddle/plunkr to show us the specific problem?

Comment: Absolutely not I'm afraid, that's why I've described it as thoroughly as I could. Table is huge, data is loaded as XML from server, and then parsed to JSON, and at last the table is created. My guess is that I somehow need to wait for the jquery to do it's job with the DOM first. Will using a $timeout service be enough?

Comment: you can use timeout, but you do not know long the actual request will take. What progress plugin do you use? http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/ ?

Comment: No,I'm using the "official" Angular bootstrap progress-bar plugin. [link](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

I have just successfully implemented $timeout to directive, but I get incredibly poor performance. But ok, that's a different issue now.

Comment: In that case, please consider posting the answer to the questions yourself.

Comment: Why not just use css3 animation instead of worrying about scripting? http://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/

Comment: I don't think that that is an option at all. I need to do 300-400 (sometimes even more) css transitions on the same page, at the same time (simultaneously). 

And I need to update values for each progress-bar dynamically. So I HAVE to worry about scripting anyway. It can only be a difference between angular directive and some kind of jquery plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes up with the similar problem, it might help him to use the [angular $timeout service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout). Problem is that if you have a lot of progress bars, like me (200 + on a single page), you'll get issues with the performance, especially with users which don't use Google Chrome.

Here's the updated 'progressbar' directive:

```
.directive('progressbar', ['$transition', '$timeout', function($transition, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            width: '=',
            old: '=',
            type: '=',
            animate: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'template/progressbar/bar.html',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            $timeout(function(){
                scope.$watch('width', function(value) {
                    if (scope.animate) {
                        element.css('width', scope.old + '%');
                        $transition(element, {width: value + '%'});
                    } else {
                        element.css('width', value + '%');
                    }
                });
            },100)

        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Here the timeout seems not destroyed on $destroy? Is it the right way on progressbars or shpould we cancel it?